# creating simple html page with typo3

Tags: html, typo3

i have just installed typo3 but i'm not able to create a simple html page. I create a new page with the "page" tool but i cannot see it with the "view" tool. I only can see "not found" in the navigator. ¿where are saved the html pages that you create with typo3?
regards.

Answer (score 0):

at first a warm welcome to the TYPO3 community!

TYPO3 does not create HTML files, but save the rendered pages in a cache system.

To get a well installed TYPO3 producing frontend output you need a few steps:

1. A root page in the page tree (your entry point to the page tree)
2. A site created with the sites module for the root page (handles domains, languages etc.)
3. A TypoScript template record at the root page (rendering definition for your page tree below the root page)

You will find documentation for this here:

TYPO3 page tree:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/master/en-us/Pages/Index.html

TYPO3 site handling:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html

TYPO3 template record:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/7.6/en-us/Tasks/WorkingTypoScript/TypoScriptTemplate/Index.html

TypoScript quick overview:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-typoscript-in-45-minutes/master/en-us/TypoScriptOverview/Index.html

TypoScript FLUIDTEMPLATE (Fluid is the TYPO3 template engine):

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/master/en-us/Index.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

May be it could be interesting for you to install a distribution first, where everything is working already, so you will get a quick result:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/Distributions/Index.html

If you have problems with your installation have a look there:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/Index.html

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @dostoyevski For some reason stackoverflow cuts my first line. So there should be a "Hi dostoyevski" :-D

Comment: i have read all those links, but i'm usable to show not even a hello world, i cannot see where is the mistake: (here's a image of what i get):https://postimg.cc/mcZGkY6x

Comment: i have read all those links but i'm unable to show a hello world: this is what i get:https://postimg.cc/mcZGkY6x

Comment: Ok, so the normal frontend works, but only the view module in BE gives you this error?

Comment: is only the vew mode.

Comment: any opinion about what could be the problem? thanks!